# GridView Control (Windows 8) incorrectly rendered

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-8, winrt-xaml

Here's the code for the GridView Control that I'm using (made on BlankPage App):

```
<GridView HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="gridView1" Margin="227,220,0,53" Width="1087">

        <Button x:Name="XboxButton" Margin="10,10,10,10" Style="{StaticResource XboxButton}" Height="200" Click="SnappedXboxButton_Click_1"/>
        <Button x:Name="PS3Button" Margin="10,10,10,10" Style="{StaticResource PS3Button}" Click="SnappedPS3Button_Click_1" />
        <Button x:Name="PCButton" Margin="10,10,10,10" Style="{StaticResource PCButton}" Click="SnappedPCButton_Click_1" />
        <Button x:Name="DSButton" Margin="10,10,10,10" Style="{StaticResource DSButton}" Click="SnappedDSButton_Click_1" />
        <Button x:Name="PSPButton" Margin="10,10,10,10" Style="{StaticResource PSPButton}" Click="SnappedPSPButton_Click_1" />
        <Button x:Name="ContactButton1" Margin="10,10,10,10" Style="{StaticResource ContactButton}" Click="SnappedContactButton_Click_1" />
        <Button x:Name="PrivacyButton" Margin="10,10,10,10" Style="{StaticResource DisclaimerButton}" Click="SnappedPrivacyButton_Click_1"/>


    </GridView>
```

The problem is when the app first loads it shows the GridView is shown like this:

(Please go here, since, I'm new, I'm not allowed to post images)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/189014

But when I click any item and GO BACK to the first page the render is fine as shown in this image:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/189015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Improve tour markup.
1. In the GridView define a style resource for buttons, or in  app resources create a base style and then use it in each button  style using BasedOn={StaticResource binding notation
2. Set the margin,width,height , as I see all buttons have same property values
3. Id you don't want GridView set width or height values automaticly, ensure you set the values in the styles

Comment: ^ Okay that helped! Thanks! I had already defined the ButtonStyles in StandardStyles.xaml. Now, I ported those styles to GridView.Resources and also set the width = height (BTW, Height was already set). The combination of these 2 did the trick. Doing only one of these didn't help.

Comment: Sure, if you don't setup one of them the GridView will try to Auto assign this value based on actuall itemsource and container, but if you assign the values the GridView preserve it.

Comment: Sorry, can't +1 your answer as I don't have 15 rep!